# How would I display es6 components in my html file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I want to display the `Root` component inside my html file.  I'm aware on how to do it with `es5` using `ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'))` but what about for `es6`?

Here's my html file:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here's my js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Testing</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My attempt above the `es5` way because I wasn't quite sure how to make this happen in `es6`, this obviously isn't working.

Note: I'm not using `create-react-app` for my project.  I'm just trying things out outside of `create-react-app` environment and instead, onto other environments.  I installed Babel and all the other stuff manually.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/5274dfa1eb31e6d22b9eddd1efc773dc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an import statement for the React DOM, because you will need it to render components to the DOM from React, unless you're importing those components from separate files.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
```

Add that after your first import statement.

Comment: hey Marcus, I tried that but  my test still isn't showing up :(

Comment: If you go to [REPL.it](http://repl.it) you can upload your react code, so that we can see it in its entirety.

Comment: Also, you may need to just refresh your cache by pressing Ctrl + F5 or Ctrl + click on refresh icon in the browser.